# How to load a module before another module loads?

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel-module

I have two modules, X and Y.

I need to load the Y module when X module loaded.

How can I do this without adding any softdeps?

Is there any other way to specify to the kernel that X depends on Y and kernel need to load Y before loading of the X?

In which way I need to change  so that I can load the Y before X without adding any softdep.

Comment: If there is dependancy kernel will load them automatically. I mean if you X calls some functions of Y. Y will be loaded before X is loaded

Comment: No, X will not call any Y functions, but Y will give some extra features to X when it is loaded

Comment: Try puting X and Y to vi /etc/modules.conf ...If you are using Debian Linux or Ubuntu Linux use file /etc/modules file instead of /etc/modules.conf (which works on Red Hat/Fedora core/Cent OS etc)

Comment: You may do `request_module()`, but usually it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use modprobe an set some dependency. Then required modules will come up automatically. or you can manually load it in any script file by calling insmod too.